# How to get table values from web form into post method python flask?

Tags: python, html, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I have the table in the web form. I will change the values from the drop down and i will submit it.
I want to get all the values from table in dictionary format into post method while submitting the page.
I will store those values in the backend database.

Can someone suggest me to get the table values from the form in post method python ?
Am using flask for front end.

html code for table creation:

```
 <table>
<tr><td>LL6cdsid</td><td>resourcecdsid</td><td>workstation</td><td>location</td><td>date</td><td>status</td><td>raiseit</td><td>changestatus</td><td>Requestid</td></tr>
{%for item in requests %}
    <tr><td>{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[3]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[4]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[5]}}</td>
    <td><a href="http://example.com/">Raise IT</a></td>
        <td><select name="status" id="status">
        <option value="RAISED">NEW</option>
        <option value="RAISED">RAISED</option>
        <option value="PENDING">PENDING</option>
        <option value="COMPLETED">COMPLETED</option>
        <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
    </td>
    <td>NIL</td>
{% endfor %}
    <td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: When you submit the form, if you use POST, then you can access the data submitted on your view function with `request.form`

Comment: I want everything in dictionary format...

Comment: then you’ll have to do that yourself I think

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden input whose value is same as the content of each cell:

```
<form method="post" action="your_flask_route">
<table>
... 
</tr>
{%for item in requests %}
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="td1" value="{{item[0]}}">{{item[0]}}</td>
...
<td><input type="hidden" name="td5" value="{{item[5]}}">{{item[5]}}</td>
<td><a href="http://example.com/">Raise IT</a></td>
...
<td>NIL</td>
{% endfor %}
<td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

> Then in flask you can get the submitted form details this way:

```
request.form['td1']
...
request.form['td5']
```

Comment: am getting this while trying to access request.form['td1']  *** werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
(Pdb) request.form['td1']
*** werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
(Pdb) request.form['td2']
*** werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
(Pdb)

Comment: html  <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="td1" value="{{item[0]}}">{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="td2" value="{{item[1]}}">{{item[1]}}</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="td3" value="{{item[2]}}">{{item[2]}}</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="td4" value="{{item[3]}}">{{item[3]}}</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="td5" value="{{item[4]}}">{{item[4]}}</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="td6" value="{{item[5]}}">{{item[5]}}</td>